# Wacom tablet clicks don't land where the cursor is in some apps

Tags: gnome, mouse, wacom

I have a Wacom Intuos Pro 4 and Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, and there seems to be a problem with the way some applications deal with clicks. The click co-ordinates seem to be scaled wrongly, so the click doesn't land where the cursor is. The further away from the top left of the screen the bigger the discrepancy is. Basically the click from the pen lands at a point about 150% of the way from the top left of the screen to where the cursor is. I have a high DPI screen that is scaled to 125%, so this might have something to do with it.

The worst (for me) culprit is DaVinci Resolve, but other applications like Krita do it too. Clicking by touching my finger on the tablet works fine, and mouse clicks are fine, it's just the pen that is mis-scaled. Most other apps, and the shell are fine. Also in Krita when I'm say using a paint tool the click lands in the right place, but when I try to click on toolbars or menus is when it goes wrong.

I tried to record a screencast, but the Gnome screen recorder doesn't seem to record the cursor, even if you click the record cursor button.